# Constraining Child Window to its parents bounds

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm looking for a way to constrain children windows that have been spawned by another WPF window and have had their owner set to that window from leaving the bounds of the window. I've tried several solutions but I haven't been able to implement an elegant solution where the windows won't flicker when they're dragged off the edge of the parent. Any help would be appreciated. The current code I have is on the locationchanged event where I check the left/top of the windows and if they're dragged off, it resets the children's position to the appropriate location.

Comment: short answer: you can't. If you need to bound the child window you should just be hosting that child window within the parent window

Comment: how would I go about doing that? I'm already setting the owner of the children window to its parent, but I've never heard of hosting a child window within the parent window. @Steve

Comment: basically moving all the child window's content into one of parent window's grid cell. If you would like it to behave exactly like a window (dragging resizing ect) then you would need to implement your own window handling logic or find a 3rd party solution

Comment: Just curious, can't you use a modal dialog/window?